# Optimization problem over matrices

Tags: matrices, optimization, numerical-optimization

Let $M^0$ be a $n\times m$ matrix whose entries are natural numbers (including zero).
Consider the following matrix score
\begin{equation*}
s(M)\triangleq \sum_{i=1}^{\min(n,m)} M_{ii}
\end{equation*}
where $M_{ii}$ is the element of row and column $i$ of the generic matrix $M$.
I want to find the solution (score and optimal matrix) of the following optimization problem
\begin{equation*}
\max_{M\in \mathcal{M}^0} s(M)
\end{equation*}
where $\mathcal{M}_0$ is the space composed by all matrix obtained by permutating the columns of the given matrix $M_0$.

**Example**

Consider the following starting matrix
\begin{equation*}
M^0 \triangleq \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation*}
in this case the optimal matrix is
\begin{equation*}
M^* \triangleq \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation*}
with optimal score $s(M^*)=3$

**Attempt 1 to solve the problem: brute force**

A possible, but not so clever solution, for the current problem is brute force: just compute each possible permutation and then pick up the one with maximum score. The clear problem of this solution is its computational cost, that is in the order of $m!$.
Hence, brute force can be used only for small values of $m$. Unfortunately, in my application typically $m$ can be in the order of $10^2$ or $10^3$, so brute force is unfeasable.
Despite this fact, this solution is still usefull when $m$ is small because it can be used to prove the optimality of other approaches.

**Attempt 2 to solve the problem: greedy optimization**

Something clever is the following: build a "good" matrix $\hat{M}$ be forcing the diagonal elements $\hat{M}_{ii}$ to be large as possible.
More precisely, the procedure to build $\hat{M}$ is given as follows.

- **step 1:** search in $M^0$ the column $M_{j}^0$, with $j\in\{1,\dots,m\}$, that maximizes its first component. Such column is the first column $\hat{M}_1$ of the proposed solution $\hat{M}$.
  \begin{equation*}
  \hat{M}_1 \triangleq \arg \max_{j\in\{1,\dots,m\}} M_{1j}^0
  \end{equation*}
  In case of multiple optimal columns, just take it one randomly.
- **step 2:** remove from $M^0$ the column $\hat{M}_1$ and call the new matrix $M^1$. Now search in $M^1$ the column $M_j^1$, with $j\in\{1, \dots, m-1\}$, that maximes its second component. Such column is the second column $\hat{M}_2$ of the proposed solution $\hat{M}$.
  \begin{equation*}
  \hat{M}_2 \triangleq \arg \max_{j\in\{1,\dots,m-1\}} M_{2j}^1
  \end{equation*}
  In case of multiple optimal columns, just take it one randomly.
- **step 3:** repeat until  $\hat{M}$ has $m$ columns.

Now $\hat{M}$ requires the solution of $m-1$ trivial optimization problems, and so seems to feasible even when $m$ is not small. However the problem is that I'm not sure that $\hat{M}$ is optimal in a global sense.

**Questions**

1. Is $\hat{M}$ optimal?
2. Is there a non brute force algorithm that guarantees the optimality of the solution? If yes, is this one computational cheaper than my greedy algorithm?

Comment: So, do you want to find the permutation of the columns of a given matrix that maximize the"pseudo-trace"?

Comment: Yes, exactly, with additional information that the matrix entries are integers and not negative.

Comment: Is the integrality relevant? As long as the entries are real, it should be fine. Hard to find the maximum of a set of complex numbers, though

Comment: Probably is relevant because since the entries are integers it is not possible to compute derivatives and gradient vectors (and so, for example, the gradient descent cannot be applied). But I can be wrong, probably one can prove optimality without involving derivatives.

Comment: Are you acquainted with linear programming?

Comment: Yes, is my problem equivalent to a linear programming problem? It will be nice because in such case the simplex method will solve efficiently my problem.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/307636/91764). Your problem is easier than this.

Comment: I've opened a new thread here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4715025/optimization-problem-over-matrices-part-2