# Optimization problem over matrices (part 2)

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, numerical-optimization, permutation-matrices

**Background**

Yesterday I've asked some questions about a [particular optimization problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4714383/optimization-problem-over-matrices?noredirect=1#comment9984714_4714383) that I have to resolve.
I've found a simple solution which it turns out to be suboptimal (I have found a counterexample that clearly shows this fact), so now I'm trying to find the optimal solution.

Thanks to the help of Rodrigo, I've realized through [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/307461/determining-if-some-permutation-of-a-vector-satisfies-a-system-of-linear-equatio/307636#307636) that my problem is "almost" a linear programming problem. Indeed, its easy to see that my problem can be formulated as follows
\begin{equation}
\max_{P\in \mathcal{P}} \sum_{i=1}^{p} (MP)_{ii}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
where:

- $M$ is a given $m\times n$ matrix whose entries are integers;
- $p\triangleq\min(m,n)$;
- $(MP)_{ii}$ denotes the $i$-th diagonal entry of the product $MP$;
- $P$ is the optimization variable;
- $\mathcal{P}$ is the set of permutation matrices that permutate the columns of $M$.

since $P$ is a permutation matrix, each column of $P$ is a vector with one component equal to $1$ and $p-1$ components equal to $0$. Similarly, each row of $P$ is a vector with one component equal to $1$ and $p-1$ components equal to $0$.
This two properties can be expressed in weaker form via the relations
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
1_p'P&=1_p'\\
P 1_p&= 1_p \\
P_{ij}&\geq 0 \qquad j,i = 1,\dots, p
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where $1_p$ is a $p\times1$ vector in which each entry is $1$ and $'$ is the transpose operator. Consequently, a relaxation of my original problem $(1)$ is given by
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\max_{P} &\sum_{i=1}^{p} (MP)_{ii}\\
\text{st} \quad & 1_p'P=1_p'\\
&P 1_p= 1_p\\
&P_{ij}\geq 0 \qquad j,i = 1,\dots, p
\end{aligned}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

which is a linear programming problem. The point is that now the optimization variables (i.e. the entries $P_{ij}$ of $P$) can be any positive real number, and so it is not clear to me if the optimum $P^*$ of $(2)$ is, as I desire, a permutation matrix.

**Questions**

1. The solution of the relaxed problem $(2)$ can be used to find the solution of my original problem $(1)$? Maybe, if necessary, I can round the optimum $P^*$ of the relaxed problem towards the nearest permutation matrix
2. Is there some integer solver for my original problem $(1)$?