# Optimization problem over matrices (part 3)

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, numerical-optimization, permutation-matrices

**Background**

[I'm working](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4715025/optimization-problem-over-matrices-part-2) on the following linear program
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\max_{P} &\sum_{i=1}^{\min(m,n)} (MP)_{ii}\\
\text{st} \quad & 1_n'P=1_n'\\
&P 1_n= 1_n\\
&P_{ij}\geq 0 \qquad j,i = 1,\dots, n
\end{aligned}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
where $M$ is a given $m\times n$ matrix and $P$ should be a $n\times n$ permutation matrix. Such problem can be formulated in the following standard form
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{x \geq 0}  \,   & c'x\\
\text{s.t.}\, & Ax \leq b \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where $x=\textrm{vec}[P]$ and
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
c&\triangleq -\textrm{vec}\left[{M}'\right]\\
A&\triangleq \left[\begin{array}{c}
-(I_{{n}}\otimes 1_{{n}}')\\
\phantom{-}(I_{{n}}\otimes 1_{{n}}')\\
-(1_{{n}}'\otimes I_{{n}})\\
\phantom{-}(1_{{n}}'\otimes I_{{n}})
\end{array}\right]\\
b&\triangleq \left[\begin{array}{c}
-1_{{n}} \\
\phantom{-}1_{{n}}\\
-1_{{n}} \\
\phantom{-}1_{{n}}\\
\end{array}\right]\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
The notation used is the following:
$\text{vec}[A]$ is the operator that stacks the columns of the matrix $A$,
$1_n$ is a $n\times 1$ vector of $1$s, $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix,$\otimes$ is the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) and $'$ is the transpose operator.

**Question**

The involved constraints guarantee only that $P$ is double-stochastic (and not a a permutation matrix). However, I've done some numerical test and it seems that the returned solution is always a permutation matrix. My question is thus the following:

- Is it true that the optimal solution of the linear program $(2)$ is a permutation matrix?  If yes, how can be shown this fact?

To be honest, I don't have a clue about how to show my conjecture. The only thing that come in my mind is that the objective is to show that the entries of $P$ can be only $0$ or $1$ (which, in additition of the double stochasticity, should be enough).

Comment: It is not true. If we make all the elements of M the same, then you can get a doubly stochastic matrix and not a permutation matrix as the optimal solution. If you have some additional assumption about the rank of M then it is true. You need to exploit the structure of your objective function, i.e., the objective is the sum of the products between the rows of M and the columns of P. For each column of P, the optimal would place all the weight onto one index.

Comment: Thank you for your counterexample dgadjov. I forgot to say some things that probably are important: (1) the entries of $M$ are non-negative integers; (2) if $n\leq m$ then $M$ has no null columns and no null rows (i.e. full of $0$s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to be careful about the word "the" in the optimal solution. It is true that **at least one** optimal solution to your linear program will be a permutation matrix. For most, but not all, matrices $M$ the optimal solution will be unique, and in that case, you'll always get a permutation matrix. (Even when the solution is not unique, algorithms such as the simplex method will give a permutation matrix as the answer.)

The reason begins with the [Birkhoff–von Neumann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix#Birkhoff%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem), which says that the polytope of $n\times n$ doubly stochastic matrices is the convex hull of the set of $n\times n$ permutation matrices. You should imagine this as a high-dimensional polyhedron in $n^2$-dimensional space, with the permutation matrices at its corners.

The expression $\sum_{i=1}^{\min(m,n)} (MP)_{ii}$ represents a direction in $n^2$-dimensional space, and to maximize it we want to as far as possible in that direction while staying in the polytope. Usually, this will lead us to a corner. The exception occurs when the direction is perpendicular to some $k$-dimensional face of the polytope (for $1 \le k < n^2$). In such a scenario, several corners will be tied for optimality, and any convex combination of those corners will also be equally good.

Comment: Thank you so much Misha!  Very clear explanation, now I can finally consider my original problem closed :)

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/618123/metrics-for-multiclass-classification?noredirect=1#comment1148892_618123